# actionscript 2.0 input text box

Tags: variables, input, textbox, actionscript-2, response

So, here's what I'm trying to do, and I, frankly, believe it should be obvious, but I can't figure it out. I am creating a very simple Artificial Intelligence simulation. And in this simulation there's an input box at the bottom of the screen (called "input" exactly). "input" has a variable in its properties that is called "inbox" (exactly). Using a key listener the script calls up a function when the enter button is pressed. This function has 2 if statements and an else statement which dictate the responses of the AI (named "nistra"). The problem is this, When I type in what I want to say, and hit enter, it always uses the second response ("lockpick" in the code below). I have tried variations on the code but I still don't see the solution. I believe the problem is that the "typein" variable holds all the format information from the text box as well as the variable, but I could be wrong, that information is in here as well, underneath the code itself. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

```
var typein = ""; //copies the text from inbox into here, this is what nistra responds to
var inbox = ""; //this is where the text from the input text box goes
var respond = ""; //nistra's responses go here
my_listener = new Object(); // key listener
my_listener.onKeyDown = function()
{
    if(Key.isDown(13)) //enter button pressed
    {
        typein = inbox; // moves inbox into typein
        nistraresponse(); // calles nistra's responses
    }
    //code = Key.getCode();
    //trace ("Key pressed = " + code);
}

Key.addListener(my_listener); // key listener ends here

nistraresponse = function() // nistra's responses
{
    trace(typein); // trace out what "typein" holds
    if(typein = "Hello") // if you type in "Hello"
    {
        respond = "Hello, How are you?";
    }
    if(typein = "lockpick") // if you type in "lockpick"
    {
        respond = "Affirmative";
    }
    else // anything else
    {
        respond = "I do not understand the command, please rephrase";
    }
    cntxtID = setInterval(clearnistra, 5000); // calls the function that clears out nistra's response box so that her responses don't just sit there
}

clearnistra = function() // clears her respond box
{
    respond = "";
    clearInterval(cntxtID);
}
```

// "typein" traces out the following

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE="20" COLOR="#FF0000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">test</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ActionScript is based on ECMAScript I'm pretty sure that you need to use `==` instead of `=` for equality comparison.

Right now your code works like this:

```
if(typein = "Hello") { // assign "Hello" to typein. always true.
    respond = "Hello, How are you?";
}
if(typein = "lockpick") { // assign "lockpick" tot ypein. always true.
    respond = "Affirmative";
}
// the else block is always false for obvious reasons
```

So you simply need to change the code like this:

```
if(typein == "Hello") {
    respond = "Hello, How are you?";
}
else if(typein == "lockpick") {
    respond = "Affirmative";
}
else {
    respond = "I do not understand the command, please rephrase";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, using that change it simply started responding to everything with the else case. "I do not understand". Even if it was a correct input.

Comment: Also want to point out that I just corrected what it traces out, it seemed to paste the wrong information when I first posted the question.

Comment: Ok, I'm currently playing around with it, and I've added 3 buttons that essentially do the same thing without having to type in the command. Here's the code for the buttons.

b_hello.onRelease = function()
{
 typein = "Hello";
 nistraresponse();
 trace("calling");
}

b_lock.onRelease = function()
{
 typein = "lockpick";
 nistraresponse();
}

b_dontunderstand.onRelease = function()
{
 typein = "dont get it";
 nistraresponse();
}
this is working correctly

Comment: So, I'm assuming the issue is in the fact that the textbox formatting is getting put into "typein" when using the textbox, and that this is what is causing the issue.

Comment: So, if anyone was following this, I have solved the issue. The problem was that I was trying to store a variable from a textbox into a variable by using the variable option in the textboxes properties. What I needed to do instead was use the script command to pull the text itself from the box. As follows.

Comment: var typein = ""; //copies the text from inbox into here, this is what nistra responds to
var inbox = ""; //this is where the text from the input text box goes
var respond = ""; //nistra's responses go here
my_listener = new Object(); // key listener
my_listener.onKeyDown = function()
{
    if(Key.isDown(13)) //enter button pressed
    {
        typein = inbox; // moves inbox into typein

Changed from this, into this...

Comment: var typein = ""; //copies the text from inbox into here, this is what nistra responds to
var inbox = ""; //this is where the text from the input text box goes
var respond = ""; //nistra's responses go here
my_listener = new Object(); // key listener
my_listener.onKeyDown = function()
{
 if(Key.isDown(13)) //enter button pressed
 {
  typein = Input.text; // moves inbox into typein
  nistraresponse(); // calles nistra's responses
 }